# Is it possible to host MERN application on Heroku using single package.json?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I read bunch of blogs about MERN application deployment on Heroku but they all are uses separate package.json for client and server!

Is it possible to use one package.json file?

[**My Project Structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crA8h.png)

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Dweep Panchal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "braintree-web-drop-in-react": "^1.1.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "braintree": "^2.22.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.0",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
    "stripe": "^8.46.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "server": "cd ./backend && node app.js",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"react-scripts start\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "../.env" });
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

// Routes
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const categoryRoutes = require("./routes/category");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/product");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/order");
const stripeRoutes = require("./routes/stripepayment");
const braintreeRoutes = require("./routes/braintreepayment");

// DB Connection
mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_NAME}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@${process.env.DB_PROJECT}-xi8tq.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_PROJECT}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected!"))
  .catch(() => console.log("Failed to Connect DB"));

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());

// My Routes
app.use("/api", authRoutes);
app.use("/api", userRoutes);
app.use("/api", categoryRoutes);
app.use("/api", productRoutes);
app.use("/api", orderRoutes);
app.use("/api", stripeRoutes);
app.use("/api", braintreeRoutes);

// Server Connection
const port = process.env.BACKEND_PORT || 8000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server Running at Port ${port}`));
```

When i deployed this application on heroku then project url shows:

**Invalid Host header**

**Whole project:** https://github.com/dweep612/ecommerce

Comment: what does your app.js file look like?

Comment: @HenryLy, Here it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quickly explain how deploying any Reactjs and express to heroku work. The goal is to generate a build folder with npm run build and then starting the server to serve static content from that build folder.

In the heroku documentation, it states that heroku-postbuild runs before the start scripts. This is a perfect place to do npm run build to generate a build folder and then using the start script to run your server code. From there your server should be using express.static and pointing where ever you generated your build folder.

That is why people like to use a server package.json because it won't interfere with the react start script. Now the problem I immediately see is that you are not using the scripts correct nor are you pointing at that build folder that you are suppose to generate.

In your package.json create a start script that starts your app.js file and then create a heroku-postbuild that will generate a build folder. Like below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd ./backend && node app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

After that you should have `app.use(express.static(<<location of build folder>>))` in your app.js . Add the code below in your app.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("../build"));
}
```

The reason I said ../build is because your build folder is outside of the backend folder.

I also checked out your entire code and there are other small configuration issue. For example, if you are deploying to heroku , you should be using `process.env.PORT`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, if your backend serves your frontend. Two `package.json` is useful when your backend and your frontend run on two separate node programs.

The `invalid host headers` are probably due to how your server handles headers, but since you didn't posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as of now we can't help you further.